# ошибка при создании файла txt

Tags: python, txt

столкнулась с проблемой при изучении создания файлов. пишу в PyCharm.

самоучка. обучаюсь по видеоурокам в youtube.  написала так:

```
file = open('data/text.txt', 'w')
file.write('Hello')
file.close()
```

у автора все получается. а у меня не хочет создать папку, чтобы дальше в ней работать.

выдает такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bogda\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    file = open('data/text.txt', 'w')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/text.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, вся проблема в том, что у автора видео в папке, где лежит программа, находится папка *data*, а у вас нет. Просто функция `open()` не создает родительские папки даже при открытии файла на запись. Для создания папок может помочь встроенная библиотека `PathLib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

filePath = Path("data/test.txt")

filePath.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

file = filePath.open("w")
file.write("Hello!")
file.close()

# ИЛИ (альтернативный вариант записи)

filePath.write_text("Hello!")
```

Comment: спасибо. получилось создать папку.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
import os
os.mkdir('data')
with open('data/text.txt', 'a') as f:
     f.write('HELLO!')
```

Флаг `a` может создать файл в папке, а функция `os.mkdir('data')` создает папку с именем `data`